# Use tinyMCE and wordpress no plugins

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to create a shortcode in wordpress to create a table without useing plugins. I need to create a shortcode that alows me to add information of days and hours. Enable for each day the hours that I want to display.

For example:
Monday: 12-13, 13-14, 14-15
Tuesday: 15-16, 16-17, 20-21
Wednesday: 08-09, 09-10, 10-11
etc.

I find this type of input field:

type   : 'textbox',
type   : 'listbox',
type   : 'combobox',
type   : 'container',
type   : 'tooltip',
type   : 'button',
type   : 'buttongroup',
type   : 'checkbox',
type   : 'colorbox',
type   : 'panelbutton',
type   : 'colorbutton',
type   : 'colorpicker',
type   : 'radio',

But I cant find a multiple inpus field. I read the documentation of tinyMCE but i'm confusing.

I will appreciate some help.